# Reading base64 from a part line in Python

Tags: python, base64

I am currently struggling with something that I feel should be basic, currently I have a program that asks for a user input and saves it as a base64 encoded string,

```
password = base64.b64encode(values['password'].encode('utf-8'))
```

where password is inputted in a PySimpleGui window. This works perfectly so that

> 'password' = "password"
>
> > password = b'cGFzc3dvcmQ='

the decode works just fine

```
password = (base64.b64decode(rig.password)).decode('utf-8')
```

however the problem comes when I save this value to a file, and try and load it back into memory.

```
 filedir = 'Rigdata.txt'
rigfile = open(filedir, 'w',encoding="utf-8")
for rig in rigs:
    rigdata = ["\n\nRig "+str(rig.number)+"\n\tRig Number ;"+str(rig.number)+"\n\tRig ID ;"+str(rig.name)+"\n\tIP Address ;"+str(rig.ip)+"\n\tFTP Username ;"+str(rig.username)+"\n\tFTP Password ;"+str(rig.password)]
    rigfile.writelines(rigdata)
rigfile.close()
```

it is stored in the file in the format

> some words; the value being saved

This is then read back into into a class line by line splitting the string in 2 and only keeping everything after the semicolon.

```
password = str(rigdata.readline().replace("\n","")).split(';')[1]
```

however when read in it returns the base64 as a string whether I do a split and call it as string or not... this then causes the decode to fail as it is the wrong length.

> "b'cGFzc3dvcmQ='"

is there any way of easily rectifying this so I can decode the password?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few encoding steps to go from that string value to the original password.

**Reference:** https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/#decodingstringswithpython

```
>>> import base64
>>> a = "b'cGFzc3dvcmQ='"
>>> a.split("'")
['b', 'cGFzc3dvcmQ=', '']
>>> b = a.split("'")[1]
>>> b
'cGFzc3dvcmQ='
>>> b64_bytes = b.encode("ascii")
>>> b64_bytes
b'cGFzc3dvcmQ='
>>> string_bytes = base64.b64decode(b64_bytes)
>>> string_bytes
b'password'
>>> string = string_bytes.decode("ascii")
>>> string
'password'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly, wish this was a little easier but it works wonderfully!